# AFNetworking synchronous request

Tags: objective-c, ios5, afnetworking

I want to use AFNetworking http client synchronously. I am not sure how to go about this. The reason i choose to do it this way is because i am making a server call on the click of a button. I dont want the user to interact with the UI until I am done processing the response. Sample code would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I've never used it but it's based on `NSOperation` can you just add it to the `mainQueue`? Also, a reminder, it's bad form to block the UI thread.

Comment: That's a very bad idea to send a synchronous request from the main thread. I recommend you to disable interactions on your UI, set a delegate to your request and re-enable your UI when the delegate is warned.

Comment: Hmm okay will try it out

Answer (score -1):

Don't. Just Don't.

In the user side it would freez everything and make your app feel buggy.
At least you can use asynchronous request and a loader like that : https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD
Exemple :

```
[SVProgressHUD show];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gowalla.com/users/mattt.json"]];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

[SVProgressHUD dismiss];

} failure:nil];
```